# ¿Cómo insertar valor y texto de radio button en otra tabla de mysql con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Cuento con una encuesta sencilla que ingresa valores de radio button a mysql usando PHP.

```
<form action="registro.php">
  <label>Selecciona tu nivel de inglés:</label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='1' name='question'>Bajo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='2'>Medio
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='3'>Alto
  </label>
  <button type='submit'>Enviar Respuestas</button>
</form>
```

Programa 'registro.php' que inserta los valores a mysql:

```
<?php
 require 'conexion.php'

 $respuesta = $_POST['question'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO respuestas (id, respuesta1) VALUES ('$respuesta')";
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); 
?>
```

Esto funciona bien y por ende únicamente ingresa el valor numérico del radio button (1, 2, 3) a la base de datos en mysql. LO QUE NECESITO es saber cómo puedo tomar el texto de el radio button seleccionado (Bajo, Medio, Alto) para también ingresarlo en otra tabla diferente con la misma estructura, pero que esta contenga los textos de la respuesta esto con la intención que se ingrese a las 2 TABLAS AL MISMO TIEMPO.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres hacer eso, puedes recurrir a Ajax para recuperar tanto el `value` del radio button como el texto que hay en él, preparando una variable `data` que contenga ambos valores y postearlos al servidor, algo así:

```
data : { question : elValue , text: elTexto }
```

Luego en PHP lo recuperas así:

```
$respuesta = $_POST['question']; 
$texto = $_POST['text'];
```

En ese caso, habría dos archivos distintos:

1. El que se ejecuta en el cliente, donde estaría el formulario y que recogería la información del mismo para enviarlo al servidor.
2. El que se ejecuta en el servidor (`registro.php`) que recibiría lo pasada en `data` por medio de Ajax para procesarlo.

Cabe decir que haciéndolo así es mucho más fácil y elegante, ya que al enviar el formulario la página no se recargaría siquiera, y podrías actualizar cualquier parte de la misma con datos recibidos del servidor. En ese sentido Ajax es la mejor opción.

### Una propuesta de solución mejor

Peeeeero, me parece un error desde el punto de vista lógico lo que quieres hacer. Lo correcto en este caso sería tener una tabla relacional que gestione los estados de los textos. El diseño de esta tabla sería así más o menos:

```
tabla: question_status
--------------------------------
id_status         text
--------------------------------
1                 Bajo
2                 Medio
3                 Alto
```

Luego, si quieres saber el texto del status, harías un `JOIN` con esa tabla sin tener que preocuparte de nada más.

```
SELECT 
    uq.user, 
    qs.text 
FROM user_questions uq 
    INNER JOIN question_status qs ON uq.id_status = qs.id_status
```

Aquí estarías accediendo al valor `text` almacenado de manera única en la tabla `question_status` evitando complicaciones de manejo y redundancia de datos.

Más aún, supongamos que hay una evolución del diseño y se agrega otro status `Extra Alto`. Nada más tendrías que insertar una nueva fila en la tabla `question_status` y agregar en el formulario un nuevo radio button para ese estatus. Todo lo demás seguiría funcionando tal cual de forma transparente.

Comment: Qué gran aporte @A. Cedano, si entendí bien en la primera opción,la variable data se encontrará en el formulario?? data : { question : elValue , text: elTexto }

Comment: Aplico el mismo proceso con la misma variable si tengo más de una pregunta con radio button? @A. Cedano

Comment: @SuriGang'sHallen la variable `data` la prepararías tú, tomando los valores de los elementos del `input`  que te interesen (generalmente por su id), o serializando el formulario, si te interesa enviar el contenido completo del formulario al servidor. De ese modo, puedes tomar cualquier elemento del DOM (la página que contiene el formulario) y enviarlo al servidor para que éste haga lo que sea necesario con esos datos.