# ¿Cómo ingresar texto de radio button con value numérico a MYSQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

En este escenario cuento con un formulario que usa radio button para ingresar respuestas usando PHP:

1
Cuento con una encuesta sencilla que ingresa valores de radio button a mysql usando PHP.

```
<form action="ingresar.php">
  <label>Selecciona tu color favorito:</label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='1' name='colores'>Rojo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='2'>Azul
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='3'>Verde
  </label>
   <button type='submit'>Enviar Respuestas</button>
</form>
```

Y cuento con dos tablas dónde ingreso por el momento las mismas respuestas usando las dos consultas en php.

registro.php

```
 <?php
  require 'conexion.php'

  $respuestaColor = $_POST['colores'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaUno (id, res) VALUES ('$respuestaColor')";
  $resultadoA = $mysqli->query($sql); 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaDos (id, res) VALUES ('$respuestaColor')";
  $resultadoB = $mysqli->query($sql); 
 ?>
```

Cómo puedo hacer que en una tablaUno se ingrese el valor numérico del radio button (1,2 o 3) y en la otra tablaDos se ingrese el texto de la selección es decir (Rojo, Azul o Verde)???

Agradezco la ayuda:.

Comment: para poder insertar en una segunda tabla esos valores que necesitas solo es necesario crear un trigger

Comment: Supongo que intentas crear una relación para saber más adelante que: `1=Rojo, 2=Azul, 3=Verde, ... 999=Color999`. Propondría algo más simple, que crees una tabla `colores_nombre` donde guardes de manera única cada identificador y su color. Luego, cuando quieras saber el nombre del color `1` haces un `JOIN` entre la tabla que guardó los valores numéricos del radio button y `colores_nombre`. Hace poco propuse una solución así en un caso similar al tuyo, lo puedes ver explicado con detalle en [esta respuesta (apartado Una propuesta de solución mejor)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297109/29967).

Comment: @A.Cedano, más bien diría que son prácticamente la misma pregunta. Hasta tienen los mismo errores, por ejemplo, no todos los `radio` tiene `name`; en las consultas `SQL` le falta indicar el `id`...

Comment: @Marcos se parecen mucho. Pero una trata de colores y otra de tamaños, el OP es diferente y en aquella pregunta el OP preguntaba sobre un modo de hacerlo vía Ajax. Pero como caso son idénticos :)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo insertar valor y texto de radio button en otra tabla de mysql con PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297091/c%c3%b3mo-insertar-valor-y-texto-de-radio-button-en-otra-tabla-de-mysql-con-php)

Comment: Son muy similares y la estructura del código es la misma espero poder implementar la opción de aquí.

Comment: Revisa nuevamente mi respuesta acabo de modificarla para que cumpla con la pregunta que solicitastes, ahora si se puede registrar tanto el numero como el nombre del color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MODIFICANDO RESPUESTA:**

**SOLUCION DEFINITIVA**:

La unica forma que veo para enviar tanto el valor del radio como el nombre del Label es a traves de una funcion en **JavaScrip**t y creando un `input hidden`.

He modificado el codigo y corregido los errores para que resuelva el problema.

**Ahora el codigo del formulario es el siguiente:**

```
<form action="ingresar.php" method="POST">
    <label>Selecciona tu color favorito:</label>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' value='1' name='colores'>Rojo
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' value='2' name='colores'>Azul
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' value='3' name='colores'>Verde
    </label>
      <input type="hidden" name="nombrecolor" id="nombrecolor">
      <button type='submit' id="enviar">Enviar Respuestas</button>
  </form>

  <script>

     // escuchar evento de click btn submit
     document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", leerRadioBtn);

     // funcion para buscar texto de radiobtn
     function leerRadioBtn() {
       // buscar valor de radio
       var nombreColor = document.querySelector('input[name="colores"]:checked').parentNode.innerText;
       // poner valor en variable input hidden
       document.getElementById("nombrecolor").value = nombreColor;
     }

  </script>
```

**Explicación:**

1) he agregado a todos los radio el atributo name="colores"para capturar el radio que ha sido seleccionado por el usuario.

2) Se ha agregado el input hidden para poder pasar el nombre del color.

document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", leerRadioBtn);

3) el addEventListener() se usa para escuchar un evento del click para el boton de submit el cual va ejecutar la funcion de leerRadioBtn

document.querySelector('input[name="colores"]:checked').parentNode.innerText;

4) con este comando se localiza cual es el radio selecionado y se toma el valor del texto del padre node que corresponde a Label.

document.getElementById("nombrecolor").value = nombreColor;

5) ya obtenido el nombre del color en variable nombreColor al input hidden.

**Aqui tiene el codigo para ingresar los datos archivo ingresar.php :**

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['nombrecolor']) && !empty($_POST['nombrecolor'])) {
    // recibir color 
    $numeroColor = $_POST['colores'];
    $nombreColor = $_POST['nombrecolor'];
    echo '<br> NumeroColor = ' . $numeroColor;
    echo '<br> NombreColor = ' . $nombreColor;

    // almacenamiento 
    require 'conexion.php';
    // para numero de color
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaUno (res) VALUES ('$numeroColor')";
    $resultadoA = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    // para nombre de color
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaDos (id, res) VALUES ('$nombreColor')";
    $resultadoB = $mysqli->query($sql); 

} else {
    echo "ERROR: Campos vacios";
}

?>
```

**Explicacion:**

1) Se ha colocado una validacion para que no ejecute el codigo a menos que tenga valor el $_POST['nombrecolor']

```
 $numeroColor = $_POST['colores'];
 $nombreColor = $_POST['nombrecolor'];
 echo '<br> NumeroColor = ' . $numeroColor;
 echo '<br> NombreColor = ' . $nombreColor;
```

2) Se asigna los valores recibidos por el POST tanto del numero de color como su nombre y se muestra en pantalla.

```
    // para numero de color
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaUno (res) VALUES ('$numeroColor')";
    $resultadoA = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

4) Se ejecuta el insert para grabar el numero del color en la tablaUno

// para nombre de color
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaDos (id, res) VALUES ('$nombreColor')";
        $resultadoB = $mysqli->query($sql);

5) Se ejecuta el insert para grabar el nombre del color en la tablaDos.

Se ha probado el codigo comentando las sentancias para registrar en la base de datos y funciona al 100%  ya que no se tiene la tabla y la conexion para la misma.

Comment: Se muy bien cual es la pregunta: ¿Cómo ingresar texto de radio button con value numérico a MYSQL? y todo lo que digo esta en lo correcto. no veo la razon para corregir la respuesta, si lees bien tambien hay un fragmento de parrafo donde pregunta: Cómo puedo hacer que en una tablaUno se ingrese el valor numérico del radio button. Esto no lo hace por que no llega el valor de los radio por falta de un valor en el atributo name

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @Alexander Rodriguez, funcionaría tener dos consultas aunque mis 2 tablas estén relacionadas por el id????

Comment: Si funciona haciendo dos consultas, lo que digo con el campo id es que no lo deberias colocar en la consulta porque generalmente este es autoincremental y no se le inserta valores. (Modifique la respuesta para adaptarla a la parte de la pregunta que no habia contemplado con lo del nombre del color)

Comment: Muy buena solución, de verdad gracias una última pregunta,,, si tengo un par de preguntas más con selección de igual manera con radio button, tendría que usar <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre"> por cada pregunta para usarlo en el mismo issets de php?

Comment: La validacion se hizo para evitar el error al tratar de leer el   $_POST cuando el formulario no envia datos, tambien evitar el error al tratar de insertar  un registro. Puedes mas adelante crear un codigo en JavaScript / JQuery que te valide los campos antes de enviarlos a registrar y dejas el archivo insert solamente para procesos de registro. Ahora en cuanto a los radio adicionales si estan dentro del mismo grupo colores, no hace falta agregar otro input hidden. si vas a crear otro aparte con el mismo requerimiento entonces si va ha necesitarlo

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas aquí:

1. Cuando postees el formulario sólo vas a recibir los datos que hay en el `value` del radio que esté seleccionado, usando como clave lo que haya en `name`. Sabiendo eso, debes normalizar el formulario, poniendo la misma etiqueta `name` a cada radio.
2. De lo dicho en (1) inferimos que por simple POST es imposible conocer el texto que hay escrito en cada radio button. Para conocer esto, si son valores fijos, puedes manejar en el servidor un array donde usando el valor numérico, saques el nombre del color.
3. Si no son valores fijos (o sea, en un escenario 1 puede ser Azul y en otro 1 puede ser Verde), lo más simple es recoger el dato en cliente y mandar la información al servidor vía Ajax (ver 1ª parte de respuesta enlazada en mi comentario).

Te muestro un código donde aplicamos lo dicho en (1) y en (2).

### En el cliente

```
<form action="ingresar.php">
  <label>Selecciona tu color favorito:</label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='1' name='colores'>Rojo
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='2' name='colores'>Azul
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' value='3' name='colores'>Verde
  </label>
   <button type='submit'>Enviar Respuestas</button>
</form>
```

### En el servidor

```
$mID = ( !empty($_POST['colores']) ) ?  $_POST['colores'] : NULL;

if ($mID) {
    #Array con los nombres fijos
    $mNames=array('Rojo','Azul','Verde');
    $mName=$mNames[$mID-1]; #Restamos 1 porque los arrays empiezan en 0
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaUno (res) VALUES ('$mID')";
    $resultadoA = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaDos (res) VALUES ('$mName')";
    $resultadoB = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    echo "Inserciones realizadas"; #Convendría verificar el estado de $resultadoA y $resultadoB
} else {
   echo 'ERROR: No se posteó ningún campo de color';
}
```

En cualquier caso, lo más óptimo sería resolver esto con una tabla relacionada que guarde en su respectivo ID el nombre de cada color.

Comment: Ya están relacionadas mi dos tablas.

Comment: @MarianaKiabeth si están relacionadas entonces no tienes que insertar `Rojo, Azul, Verde...` cada vez, sino hacer un `JOIN` con la tabla relacionada donde por el índice numérico sabrás qué color es. Es más simple, más mantenible y evitas redundancia de datos. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

una de las opciones si no quieres tener una un catalogo con relación id  texto y no quieres armar los parametros a enviar seria pasar el valor numerico junto con el texto esto si lo quieres definir directo en tu formulario y en la parte del back separar el texto.

ejemplo:

en html

```
<label>
  <input type='radio' value='1=Rojo' name='colores'>Rojo
</label>
 <label>
  <input type='radio' value='2=Azul' name='colores'>Azul
</label>
```

.....

y en php

```
require 'conexion.php'
$respuestaColor = isset($_POST['colores'])?explode("=",$_POST['colores']) : '';
if(count($respuestaColor)==2){
    $num=$respuestaColor[0];//valor numérico/
    $text=$respuestaColor[1];//valor texto  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaUno (id, res) VALUES ('$num')";
    $resultadoA = $mysqli->query($sql); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablaDos (id, res) VALUES ('$text')";
    $resultadoB = $mysqli->query($sql); 
}
```

Comment: Esta opción me sirvió gracias :)